# TSQL from 2012 to 2016, lost all performance on same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I face this issue when same query performed at least 30 times slower on 2016v, and that was only for sample data, in real life it never finish, I ran it 24hr+, I see that inflation rate is very high, having 2 rec on input produces 200K rows.
This query produce pretty complex Execution Plan and they are different. For now I solve this issue changing Compatblity level on 2016 server.
To  start I just provide general info with this pseudo code, maybe somebody can spot something right away. Note that there is  not ANSI select on FROM statement .
Going over exec plans will be my next step..... This sql is generated by legacy app originally created  to work with Oracle, they supplied us MS version later.  This some details with sample query that made this mess below:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
MS SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64) 
    Apr 27 2017 17:36:12 
    Copyright 
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )  

--aLTER DATABASE ADRO SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =110  --2012          --130 2016


SELECT --- COUNT(*)   
  Min(EVENT_INSR.PK_ID) AS PK_ID,
  EVENT_INSR.CUST_ID AS CUST_ID,
  EVENT_INSR.PROV_ID AS PROV_ID,
  EVENT_INSR.EVNT_DATE AS SERVICE_DT,
  CASE WHEN REGION_TYPE = 'P' THEN 'P' ELSE 'S' END  AS REGION_TYPE,
  Max(CASE WHEN INS_PROV.PROV_ID IS NOT NULL OR INS_TYPE_ID IN (1220,3428,2321) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       AS PROV_EYE,
  Max(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 3331 AND EVENT_INSR.PROV_ID <> 'N/A' AND CLAIM_TYPE = 12 THEN ISNULL(DISCH_DT,EVNT_DATE) END) AS S1,
  Max(CASE WHEN EVENT_TYPE = 1293 AND EVENT_INSR.PROV_ID <> 'N/A' AND CLAIM_TYPE = 15 THEN EVNT_DATE END) AS S2 
  --.... 30+ more MAX(...) to follow 
FROM
  INS_MASTER_DATES_X, 
  EVENT_INSR LEFT OUTER JOIN INS_PROV  ON (EVENT_INSR.PROV_ID=INS_PROV.PROV_ID)
       INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER           ON (EVENT_INSR.CUST_ID=CUST_ORDER.CUST_ID)
       INNER JOIN REGIST_ID_IN         ON (EVENT_INSR.REGIST_ID=REGIST_ID_IN.REGIST_ID)
WHERE 
  (EVNT_DATE <= RY_END) AND
  (CUST_ORDER.DAY_ORDER < 5) 
GROUP BY  
  EVENT_INSR.CUST_ID, 
  EVENT_INSR.PROV_ID, 
  EVENT_INSR.EVNT_DATE, 
  CASE WHEN REGION_TYPE = 'P' THEN 'P' ELSE 'S' END
```

[image]

Comment: You can specify the `OPTION (FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION)` [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) instead of changing the database compatibility level. If you need help with general query/index tuning, upload the plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question. Also, add DDL for the tables.

Comment: And turn on Query Store.  It will capture the plans from the lower compatibility level, and when you increase the compatibility level, you can force any plans that regressed.

Comment: Is that implicit `CROSS JOIN` supposed to be in there?

Comment: Tx all, and tx Steve, I also looking into this, I will check with logic expert.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Mr Guzman! Thanks!!!  I beat 2012 version time by 30%. Your hint works perfectly, this line will be easy to put into their code. I see  spilled over sort with wrong estimate  ( i put new pic), which I think give all problems. As a consultant I bit limited to giving real Plans to third parites, I need get OK to do this. Is Brentozar is your creation?  Looks like  it Agency who do some courtesy advcies// Tx again.    Sorry don't see a place to put 5Starts on your comment. Not sure why.... Best.M

Comment: Good to notice that that this CROSS JOIN in reality is nothing big:  that first table INS_MASTER_DATES_X  has single row with dates for each basket.  Tx all again.

Comment: I did more tests and sure that ANSI police will not help here.